# configurating .htaccess mod_rewrite with https redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

our server use doctrine and configured htaccess for it - redirect all requests to init dev.php script.

i have problem after add redirect to https:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/payment/
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* dev.php [L]

RewriteRule \.html$ dev.php [L]
RewriteRule \.haml$ dev.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

forwarding to https works correctly, but when accessing the payment controller via http, like http://host/payment/payment_server - redirection occurs to:
https://%{host}/dev.php
and doctrine displays error 404 - not found template dev.php
although it should open a link to the controller without redirection as specified in the exclusion rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/payment/
```

If I remove the redirect to https then everything works correctly on http.

please help configure so that it works correctly redirect to https everywhere except payment controller